# Как правильно транспонировать матрицу

Tags: python

***Как правильно сделать функцию из моего кода и чтобы она работала полностью?***
Код написал, но он не работает с некоторыми входными данными. А именно при нулях (строка = 0, колонка = 0) и при очень больших матрицах(в тестах валится на 950x764 матрице).
Функцию, которую пытался написать и код - ниже. Помогите пожалуйста довести до ума.

**Условие:**
*Есть матрица размера m × n. Нужно написать функцию, которая её транспонирует.
Транспонированная матрица получается из исходной заменой строк на столбцы.*

**Формат ввода:**
В первой строке задано число n — количество строк матрицы.
Во второй строке задано m — число столбцов, m и n не превосходят 1000. В следующих n строках задана матрица. Числа в ней не превосходят по модулю 1000.

**Формат вывода:**
Напечатайте транспонированную матрицу в том же формате, который задан во входных данных. Каждая строка матрицы выводится на отдельной строке, элементы разделяются пробелами.

**Пример вводы/вывода:**

***Ввод***

4

3

1 2 3

0 2 6

7 4 1

2 7 0

***Вывод***

1 0 7 2

2 2 4 7

3 6 1 0

**Просто код:**

```
rows = int(input().strip())
colums = int(input().strip())
a = [[0]*colums for _ in range(rows)]
for i in range(rows):
    a[i] = [int(j) for j in input().strip().split(" ")]
rows_count = len(a)
colums_count = len(a[0])
new_matrix = [[0] * rows_count for _ in range(colums_count)]
for i in range(rows_count):
    for j in range(colums_count):
        new_matrix[j][i] = a[i][j]
for row in new_matrix:
    print(*row)
```

**Пытался создать функцию из кода выше, но безуспешно. Много ошибок:**

```
def transpose(rows, colums):

    rows_count = len(a)
    colums_count = len(a[0])
    new_matrix = [[0] * rows_count for _ in range(colums_count)]
    for i in range(rows_count):
        for j in range(colums_count):
            new_matrix[j][i] = a[i][j]
    for row in new_matrix:
        print(*row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = int(input().strip())
    colums = int(input().strip())
    a = [[0] * colums for _ in range(rows)]
    for i in range(rows):
        a[i] = [int(j) for j in input().strip().split(" ")]
    print(transpose(rows, colums))
```

**Правка после комментариев Sergey и A_Vaclav**

```
def transpose(a):
    for i in range(rows):
        a[i] = [int(j) for j in input().strip().split(' ')]
    rows_count = len(a)
    colums_count = len(a[0])
    new_matrix = [[0] * rows_count for _ in range(colums_count)]
    for i in range(rows_count):
        for j in range(colums_count):
            new_matrix[j][i] = a[i][j]
    for row in new_matrix:
        print(*row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = int(input().strip())
    colums = int(input().strip())
    a = [colums for _ in range(rows)]
    print(transpose(a))
```

**Результат работы функции:**

**Ввод:**

4

3

1 2 3

2 4 5

6 78 8

6 8 9

**Вывод:**

1 2 6 6

2 4 78 8

3 5 8 9

None

**Проверка случая, когда на вход подаются нули:**

```
def transpose(a):
    rows_count = len(a)
    colums_count = len(a)
    if rows_count == colums_count == 0:
        print('None')
    new_matrix = []
    for j in range(colums_count):
        tmp = []
        for i in range(rows_count):
            tmp.append(a[i][j])

        new_matrix.append(tmp)
    return new_matrix


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = int(input().strip())
    colums = int(input().strip())
    a = [[0] * colums for _ in range(rows)]
    for i in range(rows):
        a[i] = [int(j) for j in input().strip().split(' ')]

    # print(transpose(a))
    for row in transpose(a):
        if row != 0:
            print(*row)
```

**Входные**

0

0

**Выходные**

None

**Входные:**

4

5

4 5 6 7 8

5 6 7 7 8

6 7 8 8 9

8 9 6 4 3

**Выходные: (выводит без последней колонки)**

4 5 6 8

5 6 7 9

6 7 8 6

7 7 8 4

Если я делаю так **colums_count = len(a[0])**, то матрица транспонируется нормально, но при нулях ошибка! *NoneType is not iterable.*
Пытался в конце под main() задать условие в цикле, что вывод только если **row != 0**, но это  не помогло

Comment: а почему вы не используете библиотеку NumPy? array.transpose()  # Транспонирование
(https://pythonworld.ru/numpy/2.html)

Comment: @A_Vaclav, нельзя:( надо самому без библиотек

Comment: Я бы не стал говорить что без успешно... как бы есть ошибки. И это нормально. А значит и промежуточный результат имеется!
А зачем вы матрицу с нулями создаете перед заполнением?

Comment: А почему в функцию вы передаете кроме самого массива для транспонирования еще и rows?

Comment: @A_Vaclav, просто когда гуглил  как сделать матрицу из списков самый удачный вариант заполнения был этот и он был с нулями. А сейчас после вашего комментария удалил заполнение нулями и матрица все равно наполняется. А вот в самой функции где new_matrix, заполнение нулями удалил, но возникли ошибки.
в функцию передал rows, потому что думал, что раз внутри функции есть действия с rows, то нужно передавать. сейчас убрал rows

Comment: если не запрещено использование функции  `zip`  то решение может быть очень простым.

Comment: Уважаемый мистер @SergFSM, вы не стесняйтесь. Давайте свой ответ желательно с пояснениями. Человек хочет разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def transpose(a):
    if not a: return []
    rows_count = len(a)
    colums_count = len(a[0])
    new_matrix = []
    for j in range(colums_count):# range(rows_count):
        tmp = []# берем маленький пустой мешочек
        for i in range(rows_count):# range(colums_count):
            tmp.append(a[i][j])# наполняем мал. мешочек из столбцов по строчно
        new_matrix.append(tmp)# наполняем большой маленькими
    return new_matrix# возвращаем из функции большой мешок

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = int(input().strip())
    colums = int(input().strip())
    if rows != 0 and colums != 0:
        a = [[0] * colums for _ in range(rows)]
        for i in range(rows):
            a[i] = [int(j) for j in input().strip().split(" ")]
    elif rows == 0 and colums != 0:
        a = [[0 for _ in range(colums)]]
    elif rows != 0 and colums == 0:
        a = [[0] for _ in range(rows)]
    else:
        a = []
    #print('a=', a)
    #print(transpose(a))
    for row in transpose(a):
        print(*row)
```

Comment: ОБРАТИТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ! Я переставил порядок циклов.

Comment: Добавил вывод построчно, что бы как в тестах.

Comment: спасибо большое. за комментарии в коде особенно. А по поводу построчной печати - не догадался бы сам. Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! :-)

Comment: прошу прощение, сможете помочь еще раз пожаалуйста? 
оказалось что тесты ругаются еще и при нулевых входных значениях. Нужно сделать проверку. я уже  не стал беспопокоить вас и целый день  на это потратил. Я сецчас в вопросе добавлю код, если не сложно скажите как сделать проверку чтобы работало.. а то у меня либо с нулями работает, либо без  проверки на нули..

Comment: мой код с проверкой добавил в конец моего вопроса под заголовком "Проверка случая, когда на вход подаются нули:"

Comment: А что нужно на выходе в этом случае?

Comment: не написано. скорее всего просто None. Хотя в тесте не написано что имнно ждет на выходе. Только вот эта ошибка "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2ef94895-b4a4-4ec3-bbc7-1510d89484f9", line 17, in <module>
    for row in transpose(a):
  File "2ef94895-b4a4-4ec3-bbc7-1510d89484f9", line 5, in transpose
    colums_count = len(a[0])
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Так. Читаем что такое нулевая матрица. Рассматриваем следствие в случаях m×0 и 0×n.

Comment: добавил обработку исключений

Comment: о. наконец-то тесты прошли. У меня слов нет. Спасибо. Пока искал про матрциы что вы сказали изучить.  С вашим кодом этонагляднее. Большое спасибо

Comment: я пока не могу репутацию давать из-за того что у меня мало репутации. но как только появится, проголосую за вас

Comment: Хорошо. Но вам нужно программирование подтянуть... и  я не знаю что вам посоветовать... (

Comment: да я знаю, что у меня очень слабо. на курсах в яндекс практикуме учусь. но мне сложно даётся. возможно не моё. в начале более менее было, но с каждым спринтом всё сложнее. я и так дополнительно на степике курсы прохожу бесплатные, лекции хирьянова слушаю, записи делаю, пытаюсь учить. в общем сам не знаю что делать :D

Answer (score 2):

> Помогите пожалуйста довести до ума.

Одна ошибка бросается в глаза. Что за переменная *a* в функции?

```
rows_count = len(a)
```

К переменной *a* в главной программе она не имеет никакого отношения. Если хотите использовать матрицу *a* из главной программы, то есть два варианта:

1. Объявить ей в списке параметров функции
2. Объявить её глобальной переменной

Начните с этого исправления, так как без него всё дальнейшее - бессмысленно.

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста мою правку (написал в самом низу моего вопроса).  Ввел данные и получил марицу, но в конце почему то пишет None. Впервые такое, подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего так?

Comment: то потому, что даже если в функции отсутствует return, она все равно после исполнения возвращает значение None. Добавьте в конце функции `return new_matrix`

Comment: @A_Vaclav, вот такое как раз пробовал. Я делаю print(*row) потому что это единственное что я могу придумать, чтобы вывод соответствовал условию задачи. Да return new_matrix возвращает, но не в том виде, в каком тесты заточены пройти( 
Когда пытаюсь сделать return *row , то красным выделяется, правильный синтаксис пока не нашёл. Может вы знаете?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе эту задачу можно легко решить с помощью функции  `zip`  , правда не уверен, что это допустимо в вашем случае. И в таком решении вводить количество столбцов нет необходимости (пропустил эту часть).

```
arr=[]
for i in range(int(input().strip())):  # ввод количества строк
    arr.append(input().strip().split(" "))  # заполнение списка строк (список списков)
# с помощью zip поворачиваем список и печатаем построчно 
# предварительно преобразовав списки в строки с пробелом в качестве разделителя    
print(*[' '.join(i) for i in zip(*arr)],sep='\n')
```

ввод:

```
4
1 2 3
0 2 6
7 4 1
2 7 0
```

вывод:

```
1 0 7 2
2 2 4 7
3 6 1 0
```

Comment: Видите ли в чем проблема подобного подхода... это сиюминутное решение. То есть оно годится здесь и сейчас. Но стоит чуть изменится условиям... Например: " ...и вычислите определитель полученной матрицы." И что делать?

Comment: @SergFSM спасибо за информацию о подобном подходе. Сохраню тоже. чтобы знать.

A_Vaclav спасибо что объяснили чем отличаются эти подходы друг от друга